# ng-click still fires when div is (ng)disabled

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Problem is that `ng-click` works on so event if `cancelTicket === false` it still fires `ng-click`. How can I stop that?

```
<div class="btn-block save-changes padding-10" ng-class="{'gray':cancelTicket===false,'secondary-button':cancelTicket===true}" ng-click="CancelTicket(ticketPin)" ng-disabled="cancelTicket===false" style="display: table;">
    <div class="button-container padding3" ng-class="{'pointer':cancelTicket===true}">
        <button-spinner promise="cancelPromise"></button-spinner>
        <div style="display: inline-block !important;"> @Translator.Translate("CANCEL") </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, the event occurs even it is false, you need to take care in your code if that is false use 'return'

Comment: @BhojendraNepal where in code?

Comment: In the CancelTicket function.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Event is triggered even if the `div` is disabled.

You can avoid this by using lazy evaluation of expressions like `isDisabled || action()` so action would not be called if `isDisabled` is `true`.

In your case it will be:

```
ng-click="cancelTicket === false || CancelTicket(ticketPin)"
```

Comment: Angular gives "Trying to assign a value to a non l-value" error while doing this.

Comment: This works. I have been looking for this answer for a long time :)

Comment: does this work in a ng-repeat that calls the same func but sends diff item as input? @Erazihel

Comment: same issue, perfect solution!

Comment: I would do it by ng-click="cancelTicket && CancelTicket(ticketPin)" :)

Answer (score 16):

You should change DIV tag to Button Tag.
It works for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable click events when an element with `ng-click` is `disabled`.

**jQuery:**

```
$('*[ng-click]').on('click',function(event) {
     var $el = $(event.target);
     if($el.attr('disabled')) {
        event.stopPropagation();
     }
});
```

Doing this on all DOM elements could produce unwanted results. Also, you will need to run the above on any new HTML updated on the DOM.

Instead, we can modify just buttons to work as expected.

**Angular:**

```
angular.module('app').directive('button',function() {
     return {
          restrict: 'E',
          link: function(scope,el) {
              var $el = angular.element(el);
              $el.bind('click', function(event) {
                  if($el.attr('disabled')) {
                      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                  }
              });
          }
     }
});
```

I would not do the above on `div` elements as it would be to heavy. Instead, modify your approach so that `button` elements are only used for clickable interactions. You can then style them to look like other `div` elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" ng-click="vm.handleRemove(device)" ng-disabled="status === 1">Delete</a>
```

Change **a tag** to **button tag** then OK

```
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" ng-click="vm.handleRemove(device)" ng-disabled="status === 1">Delete</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution has been to use an html directive with an attribute used instead of ng-click, so that

```
<html-tag-directive new-click="ctrl.functionToCall()" disabled="ctrl.disabled" >
```

and the directive defined as follow:

1) template:

```
<button type="button" 
   ng-disabled="disabled" ng-click="onClick()">
</button>
```

2) controller:

```
angular.module('module')
.directive('htmlTagDirective',function() {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        templateUrl:'template.html',
        scope:{
            disabled:'=',
            click: '&'
        },
        link:function(scope,element){

            scope.onClick = function() {
                if (!(scope.disabled)) {
                    scope.newClick();
                }
            };

        }
    };
});
```