# Prevent ng-click="" effect on a disabled button

Tags: angularjs

How can I prevent AngularJS to not click on an HTML button tag that has "disabled" attribute?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" disabled ng-click="something()">No Click Please!</button>
```

In this case, something() should NOT be called.

Comment: Disabled attribute would not let make click event to happen, what is happening in your case?

Comment: check this https://baudehlo.com/2014/02/24/angular-js-ng-click-still-fires-when-div-is-ngdisabled/

Comment: It asked many times check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32005918/ng-click-still-fires-when-div-is-ngdisabled

Comment: Are you sure this is really a problem? Seems like disabled does prevent ng-click. See https://plnkr.co/edit/z3IURIaoMvaXsxVuFxE3

Comment: It seems to be the effect of css-only effect to disable. When real 'disabled' is used, it fixed. Thank you all.

Answer (score 9):

You pass an expression that has to be evaluated in the [`ngClick`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) directive. If it is not evaluated true then `something()` will not be called.

Heres an example:

```js
(function() {

  angular.module('MyApp', [])
    .controller('MyController', MyController);

  MyController.$inject = ["$scope"];

  function MyController($scope) {

    $scope.disabled = true;

  }

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div data-ng-app="MyApp">

  <div data-ng-controller="MyController">

    <button type="button" ng-disabled="disabled" ng-click="disabled || something()">No Click Please!</button>

    <button type="button" data-ng-click="disabled = !disabled">{{disabled ? 'Enable' : 'Disable'}}</button>

  </div>

</div>
```

Notice you can also use the [`ngDisabled`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) directive so that if `$scope.disabled` is true, `something()` will not be called and the button will also be disabled!

Comment: Should be `disabled || something()` not `&&`

Answer (score 0):

Proper way is to use [`ng-disabled`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) which is a default directive in angular and using a scope variable to handle it to make it disabled,

**HTML:**

```
 <button ng-click="disableClick()" ng-disabled="isDisabled" ng-model="isDisabled">No Click Please!</button>
```

**JS:**

```
    $scope.isDisabled = false;
    $scope.disableClick = function() {
        alert("Clicked!");
        $scope.isDisabled = true;
        return false;
    }
```

**EDIT**

As papakia's mentioned, check the boolean variable and function so that it will not get executed.

[**`DEMO APP`**](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/15hsLrss/)

Comment: No, as the question states, **something() should NOT be called.** This fails.

Comment: @papakia Though it does not provide an answer, definitely it helps. if you have downvoted it, no comments

Comment: I did down vote this answer because the question was *How can I prevent AngularJS to not click on an HTML button tag that has "disabled" attribute?*. This answer gives the impression that the `ngDisabled` directive will do just that. On a side note, I have not down voted you before :)

Comment: It's not personal! I respect for your knowledge of the language :)

Comment: @papakia I did not take it personal dude! it happens , thanks for correcting me though!

Answer (score 0):

This solution works in AngularJS for any and all click targets using the built-in `disabled` attribute for form inputs and/or other elements using Bootstrap's `.disabled` class and it works without adding to the controller.

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" disabled="disabled" data-ng-click="something($event)">No Click Please!</button>
```

JavaScript

```
function something( $event )
{
    var is_enabled = !angular.element( $event.currentTarget ).is( '.disabled,:disabled' );
    if( is_enabled )
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Use ng-disabled.

```
<md-button ng-disabled="true"> Disabled Button </md-button>
```

EDIT ...

[Fiddled](http://jsfiddle.net/0za1sq4q/)