# ng-click is fired even when ng-disabled is true for checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

ng-click is fired even when ng-disabled is true.
How to prevent this happening.

```
<div class="fila">
  <div class="seccion">
    <div class="asiento">
       <input ng-checked="seatLayout[0].reserved " ng-disabled="seatLayout[0].reserved || result.length == parseInt(maxSeats) "
type="checkbox" value="None" id="asiento1" name="check"/>
       <label ng-class="{'selected' : seatLayout[0].reserved == true, 'notselected' : seatLayout[0].reserved == false}"
ng-click="addSeat(seatLayout[0])"
for="asiento1">{{seatLayout[0].id}}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent ng-click="" effect on a disabled button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39355373/prevent-ng-click-effect-on-a-disabled-button)

Comment: mine is for check box not for button

Comment: Your ng-click is on the label, not the checkbox. You are disabling the checkbox which will have no relevance to the label being clicked.

Comment: is there a way i can disable label?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the ng-disabled condition to ng-click like this:

```
ng-click="(seatLayout[0].reserved || result.length == parseInt(maxSeats) ) || addSeat(seatLayout[0])"
```

This will prevent the click on the label when the condition is true.